# How to set return path using codeigniter smtp protocol

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I want to set return path in codeigniter. protocol I am using is smtp but this always shows from address in return path. here is my code

```
        $emailConfig = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => '*****',
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'smtp_user' => '*****',
            'smtp_pass' => '*****',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );

        $from = array('email' => '***@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Jack');
        $reply_to = array('email' => '***@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Jack');
        $to = array('email' => $contact_email);

        $this->load->library('email', $emailConfig);
        $this->load->library('user_agent'); 

        // Set email preferences
        $this->email->from($from['email'], $from['name'], 'return_path@gmail.com');
        $this->email->reply_to($reply_to['email'],$reply_to['name']);
        $this->email->to($to);

        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
```

thanx in advance

Comment: is there any one can reply on this please